# bindingnavigator breaks when bound to a datagridview after selection change event

Tags: c#, datagridview, selection

I've used this control before and it was very straight forward. I have a data grid view which is bound to a data source. I add a binding navigator control to the form and set it to use the same binding source as the data grid view. I add a text box, which I use to filter the results that appear in the data grid view, and modify the navigator to remove the add and delete items, so all it contains is the navigation buttons an the text box. Everything appears fine until I select a row in the grid...while the row number in the navigator is correct, there is a big red "X" that spans the entire navigation bar, which spans the entire top of the form. I've included a snapshot here:[image: broken binding nav bar]

I get no warnings or exceptions, and have the debugger set to break on any exception thrown. I feel like I am missing something obvious, but it continues to "work", in that the filter works properly and the row number is always correct. Any advice for helping fix this would be greatly appreciated. The data grid view selection change does modify the contents of the form (other controls on the form) but that all works perfectly.

As far as example code, both the data grid view and the binding navigator use a sql view which was added as a data source.

```
this.dgvSerial.DataSource = this.vwSerialBindingSource;

this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = this.vwSerialBindingSource;
```

I then set the filter for the binding source to be on the text box that resides in the binding navigator:

```
 vwSerialBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '%{0}%' OR LabelProductName LIKE '%{0}%' OR SerialNumber LIKE '%{0}%'", tb.Text);
```

I do also add a "search button", with an image which is loaded as an embedded resource.

```
 // setup the search button, the image is 
            // an embedded resource
            bindingNavigator1.ImageList = new ImageList();

            Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            Stream _imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SNReprint.search.png");
            Image currentImage = Image.FromStream(_imageStream);

            ToolStripButton searchButton = new ToolStripButton();

            searchButton.Image = currentImage;
            searchButton.Text = "Search";
            searchButton.Font = new Font(searchButton.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            searchButton.BackColor = Color.Lavender;

            // Add the button to the toolstrip
            bindingNavigator1.Items.Add(searchButton);
```

There are a bunch of other controls on the form which are bound to columns in the view which are not affected.

I'm not sure what other code I should provide, so much of it is designer generated, and every other aspect of the application works perfectly. Since this problem doesn't appear until the data grid view selection changed event is raised, I have to assume that I'm doing something in this event handler to cause the binding navigator to render incorrectly.

IF there is anything else specific that I can provide that might shed some light on the problem I am more than happy to post it...

Comment: You will probably need to provide the minimal code to reproduce this issue to get an answer here. Unless you are lucky enough to have someone with the same previous issue, you haven't given enough information yet to help.